# Regex 2 in 1 for comments

Tags: regex, string-matching

I would know if someone know if it's possible to have a specific regex for comments

Here is my current regex:`@"**\/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*\/]|[\r\n])))*\*\/+**"`

This regex works fine, but this doesn't include comments starting with **//**

It is possible to have both regex together?

Like this :

```
/* Exemple 1 */

/*
 * Exemple 2
 *
 */

/*

   Exemple 3

*/

// Exemple 4
```

Also, if someone knows really good regular expressions, is it possible to find a quote that hasn't been closed?

Like this:

**`" Hello! It's just\"an example "`** -> incorrect the quote is not closed.

**`" Hello! It's just\"another \"example\" "`** -> Same, I have a quote closed and the other not closed.

Comment: You might need or be better off with something more powerful than regexes. Regexes won't handle special cases such as pseudo-comments inside quoted strings (not comments) and various escaping very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression to capture ***most*** instances of single- and multi- line comments:

```
//(.*)|/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/iP2pX9/1)

We split this into two parts by using an alternating `|`. The first part (`//(.*)`) will find `//` and then capture the following contents (in most flavors of regex `.` matches everything except newlines, perfect!). The second part (`/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/`) will find `/*` and then lazily capture the following characters (we use `[\s\S]` which will find all whitespace *and* all non-whitespace characters, since `.` does not match newlines) followed by the closing `*/`.

You will see issues when you get to things like this:

```
$string = 'foo//bar this is not a comment';
```

If you want to remove the `[\s\S]`, we can use the `s` modifier (dot-matches-newline). Now we will need to update the single-line comment to not match newlines, so `//(.*)` can be replaced with `//(\V)` (`\v` stands for vertical line characters and `\V` is the inverse of that character class).

```
@//(\V*)|/\*(.*?)\*/@gs
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/iP2pX9/2)

Final note: if you don't plan on using the information within the comments, you can remove the capturing groups:

```
//.*|/\*[\s\S]*?\*/
//\V*|/\*.*?\*/
```

---

Matching closed sets of double quotes is a little tricky, but can be done with this:

```
(?<!\\)"(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")++"
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/kS4bY4/3)

Notice that my demo has `(?!\v)` so that it does not match multi-line quotes. This should not be necessary in a real world implementation.

```
(?<!       ?# begin negative look-behind assertion
  \\       ?# literally match \
)          ?# end assertion (we can't start with an escaped quote)
"          ?# literally match "
(?:        ?# begin non-capturing group
  [^"]     ?# match a non-" character
 |         ?# OR
  (?<=     ?# begin positive look-behind assertion
    \\     ?# literally match \
  )        ?# end assertion (an escaped quote is not the end of our match)
  "        ?# literally match "
)++        ?# end non-capturing group and possessively repeat 1+ times
"          ?# literally match "
```

The [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) repetition prevents the non-capturing group from backtracking. An example of where this is necessary can [be seen here](http://regex101.com/r/kS4bY4/4).

---

[***Update: I just had an light bulb go off and made this much simpler and more efficient!***](http://regex101.com/r/kS4bY4/5)

```
(?<!\\)"(.*?)(?<!\\)"
```

Like in the first example, we use `(?<!\\)"` to find a non-escaped `"`. If we sandwich two of these around a lazily matched pattern (`.*?`), we are good to go. I also put a capture group around this so you can reference the quoted string with `\1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and do you know about quotes not closed ?

Comment: @0x1337 and just thought of a much cleaner and more efficient method for the quote problem. *See final update at bottom.*

Answer (score 2):

If you use the 's' flag in regex flavors that interpret it to be "multiline", then

```
/\*.*?\*/|//.*$
```

will match either block comments (`/* ... */`) or line comments (`// ...`).

[Regex101.com Example](http://regex101.com/r/hQ2aY0/1)

**UPDATE:**
[This regex101.com example](http://regex101.com/r/hQ2aY0/2) shows the following comment cases:

```
/* block comments */
// line comments
"strings with /* block comments */ embedded."
"strings with // line comments embedded."
"strings with // comments" // with trailing comments
```

It does use a special feature of PCRE (the `\K` operator) to reset the match after the "string" examples, so if you're using Python, Javascript, or an old PCRE version, that portion may not work.

Comment: Good work on creating an expression that can handle more edge-cases. It's still missing single-quoted strings like `'// not a comment'` and potentially some other ones. Because there are so many and OP didn't specify if they were using PCRE, I didn't bother..but take my +1 :)

Comment: @Sam: You are correct, and [this](http://regex101.com/r/hQ2aY0/3) should correct it, although my OCD flares up that it "matches" a `'` or `"` and not the rest of the regex. Meh.

Comment: Looks good and yea I hate capturing unnecessary stuff. All depends on what OP needs.